# Valid apache mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently making changes to the `.htaccess` file to mod_rewrite a few URLs. I've done some reading and came up with the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foobar\.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foobar\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.foobar\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foobar.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

So my question is, is the above sufficient to redirect the following domains to www.foobar.com, while maintaining the trailing URL (eg. www.foobar.net/booya should go to www.foobar.com/booya):

- www.foobar.net
- foobar.net
- foobar.com
- shop.foobar.com

Comment: I think this is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and actually, if you are not serving other, independent domains but those ones, and your new foobar.com is on a different server, you could just remove those `RewriteCond`.

On the other hand, if you are serving in the same server the new domain, and you want that *all other possible domains* to be redirected to `www.foobar.com` (which I think it may be your case), you could try instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^www\.foobar\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foobar.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

That way, you don't have to worry that you may be forgetting some other domain to redirect.